# Empty value from input tag JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to get value from input tag but it returns an empty string.
When I open frame source it shows something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="" class="code_item" value="00-00000159" />
```

To get value I'm trying with

```
$(this).children('td').children('.code_item').value
```

Please, help me to find the error, I'm new for this.

Comment: Sorry. " something like  <input type="hidden" name="" class="code_item" value="00-00000159" />  "

Comment: `$(this).children('td').children('.code_item').val()`

Comment: Please provide the html code relevant to this as well, and if it is an iframe and your javascript is outside, you maynot be able to access the inner components depending on whether there is a cross domain issue. And if they are of same origin, then it is still not as direct as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery use .val() instead of .value

```
$(this).children('td').children('.code_item').val()
```

Comment: or `$(this).children('td').children('.code_item')[0].value`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using jquery selectors you should use `val()` instead of `.value` :

```
$(this).children('td').children('.code_item').val()
```

Or add `[0]` to return javascript object then you could use `.value` :

```
$(this).children('td').children('.code_item')[0].value
```

It could be done also without using `children()` :

```
$('td .code_item', this).val();
```

Hope this helps.